# subtracting two matrices in matlab, the negative values in result are substituted by zero

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices in matlab,

```
> IRwindow =
> 
>   **183**  171  150  125  137
    138  167  184  173  152
    105  114  141  167  185  
    148  113  105  115  141  
    186  183  147  112  105
> 
> ILwindow =
> 
>   **201**  170  165  177  203
    181  174  167  169  189 
    154  150  156  168  181 
    187  175  158  131  144 
    173  186  183  167  141
```

I want to subtract these two matrices element-wise and get the result; for example for first element (**183 - 201= -18** ) BUT the output for this element gives zero. the outcome result will be as below:

```
> IRwindow - ILwindow

 ans =

     **0**    1    0    0    0
     0    0   17    4    0
     0    0    0    0    4
     0    0    0    0    0    
     13    0    0    0    0
```

how could I keep the real results? without getting zero for negatives in my result-matrix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the following example code:

```
%# Create random matrices
X = randi(100, 5, 5);
Y = randi(100, 5, 5);

%# Convert to strictly non-negative format
X = uint8(X);
Y = uint8(Y);

%# Perform subtractions
A = X - Y;

%# Convert to double format
X = double(X);
Y = double(Y);

%# Perform subtraction
B = X - Y;
```

For a given sample run:

```
A =

    0   15   36    0    0
    0    0    0    0    3
    0    0    0   25    0
   13    0   15    0    0
    0   49    0    0   14
```

while:

```
B =

    -8    15    36    -4   -65
     0   -47   -45   -11     3
   -18   -17   -11    25   -52
    13   -53    15   -15    -1
   -35    49   -47    -8    14
```

You will notice that all the negative numbers in `A` have been replaced by 0, while the negative numbers in `B` are displayed correctly.

Stated simply: if you use a numerical format that is not able to store negative numbers, then Matlab truncates at 0. The solution is to convert to a format that is able to accomodate "real" numbers (or a close approximation thereof) such as `double`, or perhaps in your case one of the `int` formats may be more appropriate, such as `int8`, `int16`, `int32` or `int64`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `single` or `double` on the subtraction in one line as follows:

```
 ans=double(IRwindow-ILwindow)
```

Comment: I think this will throw an error since `mtimes` is not able to dot multiply unsigned integers with logicals. Also, I'm not sure this solves the problem, as the output will still have zeros where the "negative" elements should be. Or maybe I've misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

I dont get the same problem as you: I have this code:

```
IRwindow = [

183  171  150  125  137
138  167  184  173  152
105  114  141  167  185  
148  113  105  115  141  
186  183  147  112  105]

ILwindow = [

201  170  165  177  203
181  174  167  169  189 
154  150  156  168  181 
187  175  158  131  144 
173  186  183  167  141]


IRwindow - ILwindow
```

and i get this output:

```
IRwindow =

   183   171   150   125   137
   138   167   184   173   152
   105   114   141   167   185
   148   113   105   115   141
   186   183   147   112   105


ILwindow =

   201   170   165   177   203
   181   174   167   169   189
   154   150   156   168   181
   187   175   158   131   144
   173   186   183   167   141


ans =

   -18     1   -15   -52   -66
   -43    -7    17     4   -37
   -49   -36   -15    -1     4
   -39   -62   -53   -16    -3
    13    -3   -36   -55   -36
```

Check that you are creating your matrices are being created properly (as doubles and not as unsigned integers).

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the OP is using an unsigned data format and needs to convert it to double. See my answer for more detail...

Comment: @ColinTBowers Yep, i have also added that he needs to check for his type upon creation. Your answer does look a lot better though.

Comment: Ah, I only saw your edit after posting my comment. Thanks for the validation.